# Relay and redux - initialVariables

Tags: redux, relayjs

Relay defines graphql fragments. I have one that takes the current user's ID as a parameter.

The current user ID is stored in my redux store.

If I want to set the user ID relay variable, I can do so in one of the component's lifecycle methods. However, relay expects a value to be declared in `initialVariables`. Since this is evaluated at module load time, it has no access to the redux store.

As a workaround, I've hardcoded `'NULL'` as the userId variable in relay's `initialVariables` dict. However, this causes relay to make an initial request passing this as the user ID, and then another request after the lifecycle method has run - which calls `setVariables` - to update the user ID to the real one from the store. This also causes the component to render with incomplete data until the second call completes.

Is there a better way of getting relay and redux to play together so I can set relay variables from values in redux? I don't want it to make 2 network calls for performance, and also because I don't want the component to render with incomplete data.

Sample code for what I'm trying to explain is:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {

    const relay = this.props.relay;
    relay.setVariables({ userId: this.props.userStore.id});
  }

  ...
}

export default Relay.createContainer(connect(fullStoreSelector)(App), {
  initialVariables: {
    userId: 'NULL'              // we need to pass a dud string here that
                                // returns empty data because we have to
                                // set relay variables in componentDidMount
  },

  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        user(id: $userId) {
          id
          firstName
        }
      }
    `
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use relay, I have a feeling you might want to change the way you think about your current user.

Instead of passing the id of your current user and fetch it, why is currentUser not a field on your schema ? Pass in your token in the headers and let your server return your currentUser or not.

Comment: Because I need to request data for the current user. E.g. the current user's list of likes. In that case I have a `Likes` endpoint parameterised by the ID of the user to retrieve likes for. And users can retrieve likes of other users. I have the same thing for users, so it makes more sense to just pass the ID of the current user instead of having a dedicated endpoint to get the current user's ID.